# Python and PyQt: Get Input from QTableWidget?

Tags: python, input, pyqt, qtablewidget

So, I have a very simple question:
How can I get the input from a QTableWidget and put it to some lists(first collumn to the first list, second collumn to the second list and so on...)?

I've googled but haven't really found anything...

**Update:**

Actually, I figured out this:

```
self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cellchanged)


def cellchanged(self):
    cur = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
    cur2 = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    y = children[cur]
    text = self.tableWidget.currentItem().text()
    y.insert(cur2, text)
```

But I get this error when I update the table (it just shows, it doesn't hurt the program):

```
def updatetable(self):
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(100)
        r=0
        c=0
        for x in children:
            for i in x:
                newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, newItem)
                r += 1
            r = 0
            c += 1
```

Error:

```
  if self.tableWidget.currentItem().text():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**Update3:**

Solved it:

```
    self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cellchanged)


def cellchanged(self):
    cur = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
    cur2 = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    y = children[cur]
    self.tableWidget.cellActivated.connect(self.cell) 
def cell(self):
    text = self.tableWidget.currentItem().text()
    y.insert(cur2, text)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you want? When you say "input" do you mean the current selection? Do you mean any arbitrary row at any time? Do you just want a set of list widgets to reflect the active columns of the table? Or do you just want to dump the entire dataset into list objects for each column?

Comment: What I want is that whenever I write something in the QTableWidget to be saved to a list... I have 15 columns and 15 lists, and I want items from the first column to be saved in the first list, items from the second column to be saved in the second list and so on... By the way, it would be helpfull if the items are saved in their lists according to their rows, so that an item from the first row goes before an item in the second row...

Comment: Then the answer given by @reclosedev is going to be extremely inefficient for you. I would not want to have to perform this operation every single time you change a cell in the table. What are the lists going to be used for? A list widget? Or just data? You might want to listen to signals and update as the cells change.

Comment: I think if you update your question to explain the use case (the actual problem you want to solve) you might get an even better answer as opposed to some generic approach.

Comment: Agree with @jdi. Also, looks like ``QTableWidget`` should be replaced with ``QTableView`` and ``QStandardItemModel`` (or another model).

Comment: I don't really like this option(changing to QTableView) but if it's necessary... By the way, do you know any good tutorials on signals, because I can't really understand the official documentation... And yes, I need the list for data... So, What i have to do?

Comment: @Antoni4040, try this tutorial http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/ Concrete signals for ``QTableWidget`` can be found in documentation (probably you need ``cellChanged`` or ``itemchanged``)

Comment: Still, I'm a little bit confused and need help... I've uploaded my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453256/python-and-pyqt-run-function-from-another-class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a QTableView, and a set of QListView objects, with a single QStandardItemModel. The benefit of this approach is you only need to maintain data in one spot: the model. The views simply reflect whatever is in the model.

In this example, each list is set to view a different column. Watch what happens when you change data. It updates everywhere. This is because internally the model is emitting signals when its data changes. The views simply listen to the model. If you didn't want to use QListView and simply wanted some basic list data structures, you would manually connect to signals emitted from the model, and update your data on demand.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.vlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.list1 = QtGui.QListView()
        self.list2 = QtGui.QListView()
        self.list3 = QtGui.QListView()      
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.list1)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.list2)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.list3)

        self.vlayout.addLayout(self.hlayout)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(10,10,self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.list1.setModel(self.model)
        self.list1.setModelColumn(0)
        self.list2.setModel(self.model)
        self.list2.setModelColumn(1)
        self.list3.setModel(self.model)
        self.list3.setModelColumn(2)

        self.populateTable()

    def populateTable(self):
        for row in xrange(10):
            for col in xrange(10):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem('%d-%d' % (row, col))
                self.model.setItem(row, col, item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, jdi, but it might take some time before I check it because I'm busy reading that book you told me...

Comment: Happy learning! Hope one of us gave you a decent answer. Let me know if you need more explanation on this one.

Comment: I appreciate your help, jdi... By the way, I read the chapter about classes from "Learning Python": Everything I did in my program was wrong!!! It was very stupid from my side to try to create GUI without knowing about classes...

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Is this still an open issue or is it resolved? I am having trouble following when the answer is accepted but there are consequtive updates about new issues.

Comment: Actually, I think that I accepted it by mistake, thinking that I was accepting the other question you answered...

Comment: Well here's the deal: I don't like your solution much because it seems like I need to change a lot (which I don't want to) so I tried to figure it out myself. But, what I've done creates this error I'm speaking of, and there's one more problem: When I trie to change a cell, it doesn't update it's object in the list but appends a new item... So, I would be gratefull if you could rewrite your solution to match my program or solve my problem...

Comment: I am sorry you don't like my solution much. You don't really have to change all that much besides working with the model directly for data instead of the view. Your approach (including the other question I ended up answering) was getting you into a very messy situation. My goal was to try and steer you in a direction that would cause you less headache down the line. Sometimes you have to break things down and bit and rebuilt to get them on a happier track. This answer explains how to sync a view and a model. I did not want to reinforce your usage of global lists.

Comment: Also, as much as I love to help, what is going on here is that you are using these questions to actively debug your code step by step. You will post a question, then try an answer but have problem, then update 1,2,3+ times with new exceptions. It's not very easy to use this site for that purpose because people want to post answers to clear questions...not ones that will continue to change and require many more updates to support the OPs learning curve. What I recommend you do is ask specific questions and when an answer addresses it, accept it. But if you have new problems, ask a new question.

Comment: Can I do with this lists what I can do with normal lists, append, insert, search by index... Because it's very important that I can do this things...

Comment: Yes, actually it has even more functionality than a normal list: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstandarditemmodel.html . You can actually "find" by searching values. In addition to insert, append, index... If at any point you wanted to dump a section of data, there is no trouble in doing it from the model.

Comment: Do I really need to change from QTableWidget to QTableView?

Comment: Do you know any tutorial for QTableView and QListView?

Comment: You dont need to change. I am only suggesting the efficient path. You can make it work with a widget but you will have to manage duplicate data between them all. There is an official doc on model/view: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/modelview.html

Comment: Come on, couldn't you say that from the beginning? I'm really fond of the QTableWidget, and I feel very comfortable using it... Anyway, I'll ckeck it out, thanks a lot...

Comment: My friend....I said in very early comments that working with a QTableWidget is inefficient for your problem. You already had an answer from @reclosedev using a QTableWidget. I was taking a different direction. The Q<view>Widgets are a convenience for when you only need a one-off display of data and you don't expect to have multiple views with a single data source. You are perfectly free to use whatever approach you want.

Comment: Could you give a little bit more pythonic example? I know nothing, really, about C++ and I can't understand much...

Comment: How is my answer not a pythonic tutorial? It uses both a QTableView and multiple QListView's with a model. The C++ example also almost translate literally. Here is a slightly older QTableView example with a custom model: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/pyqt-43-qtableview-qabstracttablemodel/

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the table. QTableWidget contains [rowCount()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidget.html#rowCount) rows. Items are accessible with [item(row, column)](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidget.html#item) method. See also [QListWidget documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistwidget.html) for info on populating it.

Code may look like:

```
def copy_table_column_to_list_widget(table, column, list_widget)
    for row in range(table.rowCount()):
        text = table.item(row, column).text()
        list_widget.addItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem(text))

copy_table_column_to_list_widget(table, 0, list_widget1)
copy_table_column_to_list_widget(table, 1, list_widget2)
# and so on... or write a loop
```

**upd**

```
def table_to_list(table):
    result = []
    num_rows, num_cols = table.rowCount(), table.columntCount()
    for col in range(num_cols):
        rows = []
        for row in range(num_rows):
            item = table.item(row, col)
            rows.append(item.text() if item else '')
        result.append(rows)
    return result
```

Result will have the following format:

```
[['11', '12', '13'], ['21', '22', '23']]
```

Comment: Actually, I ment a Python list... And it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"...

Comment: It seems that it does that because there is nothing in that column when the program opens, because I haven't written anything yet... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Antoni4040, see updates in answer. Now if table cell is empty, resulting list will contain empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler with PyQt5...

```
self.gui.table_widget.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)

@pyqtSlot()
def cell_changed(self):
    try:
        self.cell = self.gui.table_widget.currentItem()
        self.triggered = self.cell.text()
        print(self.triggered)
    except:
        pass
```